# Hashing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

Given a hash, modify the hash to contain only those entries whose key is a String.  eg:

```
input_hash = {"100" => "gg", 201 => "wq", "str" => 10, "cruise" => 55, 333 => 43, 1 => "rb", "tea" => "1"}

output: {"100" => "gg", "str" => 10, "cruise" => 55, "tea" => 1}
```

I don't know how to solve this, can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: What have you tried? What worked or didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-select):

> Returns a new hash consisting of entries for which the block returns true. If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

Example:

```
h = {foo: 0, bar: 1, baz: 2}
h.select {|key, value| value < 2 } # => {:foo=>0, :bar=>1}
```

In your case:

```
input_hash.select { |k, v| k.is_a? String } # => {"100" => "gg", "str" => 10, "cruise" => 55, "tea" => 1}
```

Reference: https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-select

Answer (score 0):

"...modify the hash to contain only...": [select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-select)

"...entries whose key is a String": `key.is_a? String`